# How to improve performace of LARGE imports using Doctrine 2

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, innodb

I have about 1 million records that i need to import. I have been looking all over the web for ways to improve and speed up this process. Currently my application connects to 1 database does a select on a table with about 2.2 million rows, This select constantly takes about 10-13 seconds. I am selecting 10,000 rows with this query.

```
$results = $em->getRepository('...')->createQueryBuilder('x')
              ->where('...')
              ->setFirstResult($index)
              ->setMaxResults($maxResults)
              ->getQuery()
              ->getResult();
```

I then proceed to iterate over each of these rows and do 2 lookups in another database, use those entities to create a new entity and using a transaction insert all 10,000 new entities at once.

```
$secondEm->transactional(function($em){
    foreach($results as $result){
        $value1 = $em->getRepository('A')->findOneBy(array('value'=>$result->getValue()));
        $value2 = $em->getRepository('B')->findOneBy(array('value'->$result->getValue()));
        $newEntity = new Entity();
        $newEntity->setValue1($value1)->setValue2($value2);
        $em->persist($newEntity);
    }
    $em->flush();
});
$secondEm->clear();
```

The problem i am having is this import time gets progressively larger for every subsequent insert. The first 10,000 takes about 60 seconds, the second takes 100 seconds and then from there it seems to increase about 5-10 seconds every new insert.

I have read that for innodb tables doing large inserts you should disable foreign_key_checks and unique_checks, but i dont know how to do that for a doctrine transaction insert.

Any suggestions on how to disable those checks or even a better way to do this import will be appreciated.

**STATUS**

The select query also now seems to be increasing in time. The last query:

```
$maxResults = 10000;
$index = 470000;
```

Took 97 seconds to do the select, and the import took 173.

**IMPORTANT**
This process happens once per request, i have a javascript action that will auto submit the a blank form and this all happens on POST, I realize this may be better running from a command since it would all be on the same server but are there any other ways to optimize this?

**Interesting**

Now there have been about 650,000 records inserted and it seems to have leveled out. The select query takes between 60-70 seconds and the Import query is taking about 170 - 180 seconds for a total process time of 230-250 seconds.

Comment: Don't use doctrine for large inserts. There's a big a overhead when using an ORM for that. If you need a real fast bulk insert do a shell script.

Comment: I suppose i could write the whole thing in straight SQL but lets assume for some arbitrary reason that it has to be done with doctrine :D

Comment: Is this inserting rows in only one table or does the entity have relations that also need to be added?  If its only one table, do it through a database program such as MySql WorkBench or similar for the type of database.  If there are related entities, BUT you will not add rows to those other tables, create a new entity that has the same entity structure excluding the entity relationships and use doctrine to insert the new rows.  This will improve the speed when doing inserts, but cannot be used in your actual application for anything else.

Comment: So have another entity that just uses integer as the column type for the fields that are associated then just get the IDS and insert with those?

Comment: That seems to have made no difference. It is still increasing in time for each subsequent insert.

Comment: you have to NULL $results every time before you fetch the next 10000

Comment: The results are nulled because when I fetch the next 10,000 it's in a new request to the server. This is being run in a controller action on post. I know it's not the most ideal but this way.

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine keeps track of all your retrieved entities in the Unit of Work. With every flush doctrine will lookup for entity changes to determine which `INSERT` statements to construct. When the Unit of Work size grows everything will slow down exponential.
You have to call `clear()` on the entityManager to remove the entities from memory which you don't need anymore. See http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/batch-processing.html

```
$secondEm->transactional(function($em){
    foreach($results as $result){
        $value1 = $em->getRepository('A')->findOneBy(array('value'=>$result->getValue()));
        $value2 = $em->getRepository('B')->findOneBy(array('value'->$result->getValue()));
        $newEntity = new Entity();
        $newEntity->setValue1($value1)->setValue2($value2);
        $em->persist($newEntity);
    }
    $em->flush();
    $em->clear();
});
```

Comment: Sorry i was calling clear, after the transactional, wouldnt calling it inside remove the transaction?